# Why my object isn't hide in scrollTo jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have no idea why my browser don't hide the scroll up icon when is on the top of site. Can someone tell me more about it?

```
<script>

    jQuery(function($)
    {
        $.scrollTo(0);
        $('.tothetop').click(function() {$.scrollTo($('body'), 1000); });
    }
    );

    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if($(this).scrollTop()>300) $('.tothetop').fadeIn().top;
        else $('.tothetop').fadeOut();      
    }
    );

</script>
```

.tothetop class is a target of  marker.

Comment: It would really help if you add all relevant information and code. Like the html code.

Comment: <a href="#" class="tothetop"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></a>

Answer (score 0):

As per code you have given it seems you need to add object to calling function **scrollTo()** having two parameters for x-axis and y-axis

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
$('.tothetop').click(function() {$.scrollTo($('body'), 1000); });

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(this).scrollTop()>1000) $('.tothetop').fadeIn().top;
    else $('.tothetop').fadeOut();      
}
);
```

Try the above code for the requirement you have mentioned.
Hope it helps.

Comment: scrollTo is working good, but scrollTop isn't hiding .tothetop object. Console shown: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function
    at index.html:34
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Are you using jQuery ‘slim’ version or ‘full’ version? Because it’s running well on my machine.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>
  
  jQuery(function($)
  {
   $.scrollTo(0);
   $('.tothetop').click(function() {$.scrollTo($('body'), 1000); });
  }
  );
  
  $(window).scroll(function()
  {
   if($(this).scrollTop()>1000) $('.tothetop').fadeIn().top;
   else $('.tothetop').fadeOut().top;  
  }
  );
  
 </script>

</head>

Comment: It's a .min version